# Typescript CRA Jest import TypeErrors - undefined imports?

Tags: typescript, import, jestjs, create-react-app, ts-jest

I'm experiencing a set of errors in my React project:

```
TypeError: (0 , date_1.formatDate) is not a function
      13 |
      14 | const DATE = new Date();
    > 15 | const DATE_VIEW = formatDate(
         |                               ^
     ...
 
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/common/constants/date.ts:5:45)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/common/utils/date.ts:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/tables/actions.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/tables/index.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/common/utils/orders.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/MainPage/convertValue.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/MainPage/convertValue.test.ts:2:1)


Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')

      at Object.TEXTS (src/common/texts/index.ts:35:32)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/api/ordersService.ts:140:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/api/api.ts:4:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/allTables/thunkActions.ts:8:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/allTables/index.ts:5:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/utils.ts:43:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/tables/actions.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/tables/index.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/common/utils/orders.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/common/utils/date.ts:21:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/common/texts/index.ts:12:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/MainPage/getWidgetText.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/MainPage/getWidgetText.test.ts:3:1)


FAIL  src/store/utils.test.ts

  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: _ordersService.default is not a constructor


      33 |   public client = new ClientService();
      34 |   public widget = new Widget();
    > 35 |   public orders = new OrdersService();
         |                   ^
   ...

      at new ApiService (src/api/api.ts:15:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/api/api.ts:25:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/tables/thunkActions.ts:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/tables/index.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/common/utils/orders.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/api/ordersService.ts:5:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/utils.ts:5:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/utils.test.ts:1:1)
```

that seem to have the same reason.

The errors occure occasionally not depending on the tests modifications. The imports (named/default) are implemented properly - the app works well. The aliases are handled in jest.config.ts
`moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],`, relative importing doesn't help.

After many modifications and runs of CRA (5.0.1) `react-scripts test`, installed Jest 29.1.2 with ts-jest upon with the whole setup - running directly is the same story.

Failing tests don't even run, others run and succeed. At some points of the history they all succeed. I've seen some similar issues on Stackoverflow where updating Jest to newer versions helps, but neither different Jest versions, nor synchronising it's version with additional packages (like @types/jest) versions helps me.

What are possible reasons? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into this issue in one of my CDK projects. The problem I discovered was that I had compiled `.js` files alongside my `.ts` files in my working directory. The relative imports selected the stale `.js` files instead of compiling the `.ts` files as another es module. These `.js` files were generated after running `cdk deploy` locally.

**Solution: delete any `.js` files alongside your `.ts` files.**

I hope this helps someone else in the future.